# Direct Mail: FEHLER Die HTML Inhalten können nicht ausgelesen werden

Tags: typo3, newsletter, typo3-6.1.x

Since I've changed the Website **from http to use https instead**, the Newsletter can not be generated anymore in TYPO3.

I'm using following Extension to send the newsletter:
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/direct_mail

Following **error message** turns up:

```
FEHLER
Die HTML Inhalten können nicht ausgelesen werden.
```

I've checked following Settings:

```
 - Error Logs (php and apache), nothing in there
 - php settings (allow_url_fopen http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php), setup the way it should
 - checked the www's blogs but didn't find a working solution
 - the changes for ssl: domain record changed in typo3
 - htaccess forward from http to https
 - tried to send an external link (didn't work either)
 - checked for the boundries
 - checked for the right domain-settings
 - deprecation log didn't contain anything either
 - switched errors on (no alert or message concerning this issue)
 - typo3 configuration (curl is still on)
```

Any Idea how to solve that issue?

I've actually tried several forum settings to solve the issues but didn't get along so far.

Comment: .htaccess Password Directory Protection isn't activated, so this obviously can't be causing the problem

Comment: Idea: Certificate verification fails, because some root certificate is missing. Try to fetch a page using curl from the command line, maybe it is reproducible that way.

Answer (score 2):

is the backend also using https? basically, direct_mail uses the same protocol as TYPO3 BE, except if UseHttpToFetch is activated.

Please check following:

- fetch the page manually using wget or curl directly from the server (SSH to the server)
- check in the extension config if "UseHttpToFetch" is set.

Answer (score 1):

Last but not least my college once more solved this issue:

There seemed a Core-Bug in:

```
2328: // PATCH
2329: // CURRENT FILE: typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
2330: // CONCERNING: typo3_src-6.1.5
2331: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


The message now is: Seite ist erfolgreich ausgelesen.
```

Thanks for your help guys! 
Thanks Nico for that patch!

Comment: Yes, the problem often occures wehn using self signed certificates while developing or testing. Here is a bug report: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75908

Answer (score 0):

In my case Direct Mail reported this problem, when I used a HTAccess password.
The easiest way to test it, was to remove this password access for a minute. :)